# Cannot get a script to accept variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing my first bash script to automate a back up. I'm stuck almost on the first hurdle.

I want use variables to make a file name for a tar archive. I want a filename that looks like `hostname date time.tar.bz2`. I can get that on its own using `$(hostname)_$(date +"%FT%T")`, but I can't seem to work it into a variable.

My "test script" looks like this:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash


NAME=$($(hostname)_$(date +"%FT%T"))

tar -cjvf "$(NAME).tar.bz2" testing testing2
```

(where `testing` and `testing2` are dummy directories for, well, testing.)

Unfortunately, it does this:

```bsh
$ scripts/trial.sh
scripts/trial.sh: line 6: NAME: command not found

Thu Jun 10 23:11:06 AEST 2021
```

I've tried to breakdown the declaration of `NAME` as a work around

```bash
#! /bin/bash

## test of bits and pieces

NAME=$(hostname)_$(date +"%FT%T")
NAME_VAR=$(NAME)

Test=$(date)

echo $NAME_VAR
echo $Test

tar -cjvf "$(NAME_VAR).tar.bz2" testing testing2
```

Which gets the following in terminal:

```
$ scripts/trial.sh
scripts/trial.sh: line 6: NAME: command not found

Thu Jun 10 23:34:37 AEST 2021
scripts/trial.sh: line 13: NAME_VAR: command not found
testing/
testing2/
```

I just cannot see why this should be happening. What am I missing?

Comment: At least GNU tar doesn't like your date format with colons (see option `-f`).
It expects a remote hostname/IP before the colon and a path after the colon.

Comment: "_I'm writing my first bash script to automate a back up. I'm stuck almost on the first hurdle._" you might want to consider using an existing solution. Backups are important enough that creating them from your first scripting attempt is a good challenge but perhaps not well advised

Answer (score 1):

If these are your first attemts at shell scripting, I would recommend using [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to "proof-read" shell scripts; it is also available as standalone program on many Linux distributions.

For the problems you are facing: You seem to be mixing up the shell and Makefile syntax for dereferencing variables. In shell, `$NAME` is the value of the variable `NAME`, whereas `$(NAME)` would try to execute a command `NAME` and return the output of that command - a so-called "command substitution" (which you correctly used in filling `NAME` in your "test of bits and pieces" workaround).

So, the corrected script would look like

```bsh
NAME="$(hostname)_$(date +"%FT%T")"
tar -cjvf "$NAME.tar.bz2" testing testing2
```

As a side-note

- all-uppercase variable names should not be used unless you export them as environment variables to the shell, since they might otherwise clash and overwrite essential environment variables, such as `$PATH`.
- be sure to correctly [quote your variable references](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary), *in particular when a variable contains a file name*. Otherwise, your shell script may stumble on file names with special characters like spaces, `*`, `?`, newlines (yes, even these are allowed in file names!) and the like.

I would recommend you to have a look at

- [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
- The [GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)

for further reading.

Comment: See also `uname -n` as a standard equivalent of `hostname`. The `bash` shell also sets the `$HOSTNAME` variable. (`printf -v file "%s_%(%FT%T)T.tar.bz2" "$HOSTNAME" -1` as a builtin way to do it).

Comment: This is great, thankyou. The shellcheck thing is particularly useful.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) is to that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be:

```
NAME=$(hostname)_$(date +"%FT%T")
```

With the way that you have it, it's going to use command substitution and treat the output as a command and because it doesn't exist, you'll get the error.

The last line could just be this:

```
tar -cjvf "$NAME.tar.bz2" testing testing2
```

For future reference, you can use shellcheck.net to verify your scripts.